# Need help finding an efficient way to export spritesheets with many animations and directions

Tags: camera

I’m the solo developer of a game called Conscript, which uses 3D models animated and exported at low resolution sprites: https://twitter.com/ConscriptGame. There is a topdown angled view so every animation technically needs 5 different sprite directions to cover the full 8 cardinal directions.

Admittedly I am a massive noob when it comes to blender, and have managed to make things work so far - but I’m in need of a more optimised solution.

So far I’ve been using this add on: https://blendermarket.com/products/get-sheet-done to export every animation as an individual sprite sheet with all 5 camera directions needed for the game. I do this for every animation separately (aim, run, etc) and then combine all the separate sprite sheets into one big one on Photoshop. After this massive sprite sheet is created, I just import them all into GameMaker so I can use them in the game. This is of course very time consuming, because there are many animations and 5 directions for all of them. And, if god forbid I have to change a character design or colour, I have to do it all over again.

Would it hypothetically be possible to have Blender create one enormous spritesheet with all 5 directions for every single animation in one single process? Without me having to stitch together all the separate spritesheets afterwards. If so I can just get Game Maker to create sprites directly off the spritesheet, meaning if I ever had to swap the spritesheet out with a new one it wouldn’t cause any issues.

The only way I can figure doing this with my limited Blender knowledge would be to set up separate copies of the same character model each with their own 5 cameras in the same workspace. This seems silly though as there are 15+ different animations needed. And if I wanted to change the character model I’d have to do it 15 times…

Ideally, if I could just swap the character model and run some sort of batch process to create a new spritesheet but with a different model, it could save massive amounts of time and frustration. GameMaker is a 2D engine so I don’t really have any other alternatives other than sprites. If I can figure out a solution to this it would allow me to have alternate costumes within the game, and just greater character model variety in general.

I’m not sure if this would even be possible but I figure it’s worth asking some Blender experts anyway. Hopefully this makes sense to some of you. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey Jordan - I just published a [free Blender addon](https://github.com/chrishayesmu/Blender-Spritesheet-Renderer) that does some of this today. Check that out and feel free to open an issue on Github if it's lacking something.